# Is ther a way to directly convert Object Id to String when querying with Mongoose?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm using a Next.js 13 Server Component that queries all documents using find() with Mongoose and passes down the document array to a Client Component.

The problem is: Next.js is complaining that I can't pass down a complex object with a toJSON method, which I understand, you're supposed to only pass down simple objects with primitive type fields.

I tried using find() with a .lean() to convert every complex object of the query array into a plain object. It worked for most fields, but the _id one didn't convert and instead is passed down as a ObjectId type.

This is my code:

```
async function getData() {
  await dbConnect()

  return await Weight.find().lean()
}

export default async function Page() {

  const data = await getData()

  return (
    <main>
      <Form />
      <Records data={data} /> // Client Component
    </main>
  )
}
```

This is the warning I'm receiving:

> Warning: Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Objects with toJSON methods are not supported. Convert it manually to a simple value before passing it to props.
> {_id: {}, weight: 123, date: Date, __v: ...}
> ^^ (this arrow points to the _id field in the console)